# Websocket vs SockJS object

Tags: javascript, websocket, sockjs

I am wondering why you are able to initialize a normal javascript websocket with:

```
 var socket = new WebSocket('ws://example.com/myprefix')
```

But with SockJS you need to call a normal http(s) url:

```
var sock = new SockJS('https://example.com/my_prefix');
```

Why doesn't SockJS allow 'normal' ws urls?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The websocket protocol, starting with `ws:` is defined in [RFC6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455).

Whilst future implementations of the protocol may get dedicated port numbers  for secure and non secure traffic, at the moment (2018) the protocol is initiated by making an HTTP request with an upgrade header to change protocol to WS. (Refs [1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-1.1), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) & [3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/1.1_Upgrade_header)).

Use of websockets and `ws` protocols requires client support of the [websockets API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) and server support of the protocol upgrade header and websocket communications.

[SockJS](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client) is like a pollyfill for websockets that will fall-back to available communication channels if websockets are unavailable. Per the readme.md file,

> "SockJS is intended to work for all modern browsers and in environments which don't support the WebSocket protocol -- for example, behind restrictive corporate proxies.

Both websockets and SockJS require support on the server.  E.G. for node, either [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) or [SockJS for node](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node). The readme.md file for SockJS state that the server will accept raw requests using the `ws:` protocol header but doesn't mention on which port.

If the client side request doesn't accept `ws` URL's I suggest assuming it was written around assumptions of making an initial HTTP/HTTPS request to determine support. Perhaps an update request might expand the protocols accepted in the URL!

Comment: As in 2022, sockjs-client 1.6.1 I got the error "The URL's scheme must be either 'http:' or 'https:'. 'ws:' is not allowed."

Comment: @Qiulang Yes, the requirement remains hardcoded in v1.6.1 [socketjs-client.js:676](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client/blob/main/dist/sockjs.js#L676). IMHO,  [2.1 Connections](https://websockets.spec.whatwg.org//#websocket-connections) and [2.2 Opening Handshake](https://websockets.spec.whatwg.org//#websocket-opening-handshake) of the Websockets Living Standard, and the first line of [Getting Started](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client#getting-started) on GitHub provide reasonable support for leaving `sockjs-client` unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just have a hard time to understand why we still need SockJS in 2022 as websocket support is ubiquitous and if we really need a fallback why not socket.io